# odd PHP behaviour executing a shell command using a cron

Tags: php, linux, cron

I have a  very odd problem . I am using following code to save clamd CPU value using top

```
<?
$clamd_load=rtrim(shell_exec("/usr/bin/top -n1 -b -c | grep \"bin/[c]lamd\" | grep -E -io \" [0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1}[ ]{2}[0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1} \"  | awk '{print $1}'"));
if ($clamd_load!=""){
shell_exec("echo \"-$clamd_load-\" >> /tmp/clamd_cpu");
}
?>
```

If I execute this php script from console it run correctly returning the correct $clamd_load value

If I execute this php script using a root cron , the script simply saves this

```
--
--
--
```

returning an empty $clamd_load . Why the script returns the correct $clamd_load value if I run it from console and why $clamd_load returns nothing if I run the same script using a root cron .

I run often php scripts as cron (with shell commands in the script) and I never seen this problem before. If I use a ps instead of top command it works. Why top should not be executed in my php script using a root cron ?

Answer (score 0):

The cause is explained here 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/95877/output-of-top-gets-truncated-to-80-columns-when-run-by-cron

Solved using COLUMNS=200 before top